# Convert datetime to RFC 3339

Tags: php

My input date is `2014-03-10 05:40:00`. How can I convert it to RFC format like `2014-3-10T05:40:00.000-00:00`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) another option added in php5 like this

```
$datetime= date("c", strtotime("2014-03-10 05:40:00"));
echo $datetime;  //Output : 2014-03-10T05:40:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 26):

RFC3339 is one of the [predefined format constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339) of the `DateTime` class.

```
$inputDate = "2014-03-10 05:40:00";

$datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $inputDate);

echo $datetime->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
```

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to add that the [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339) for this can also be used with `date()`. All of these:

```
date(DATE_RFC3339);
date(DATE_ATOM);
date(DATE_W3C);
```

return an RFC3339 formatted date time string and are the equivalent of:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
```